# Get permission for newTrigger in Add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

In a Gmail Add-on, I have:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("timedFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .after(5 * 1000)
  .create();
```

However, when this runs, I get this error message:

> You do not have permission to call newTrigger

How do I get this permission?

Answer (score 2):

Finally noticed this on [one page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions):

> You can't create or use Apps Script simple or installable triggers in a Gmail add-on.

Comment: Have you found a workaround  @GlenLittle, to be able to run a function every x minutes? I'm interested too.

Comment: @Basj - I gave up on that requirement for now.

Comment: Me too @GlenLittle... Being curious: has your Gmail addon be accepted and is published [here](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/category/works-with-gmail) yet? How long does it take to get published?

Comment: @Basj I've started that application, but haven't heard yet... so I can't tell you!